# solution/alternative for dropdown menu with 100+ entries wanted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html form that have one field that need to be filled with a value that match a selection from my database.
This is a typical form where you fill in contact information for a person, and then you assign a value based on a selection from the database.  This selection will contain results between 10 an 200 hits..

A dropdown menu would fit to the layout and user interaction, but having 150 entries in a dropdown does not feel like a good solution.
Any suggestion for how to handle this in a nice and simple way? Simple is the keyword.
PHP and MySQL is used.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Dropdowns` that offer typeahead search are quite common these days; but normally that's handled in javascript rather than in PHP

Comment: Yes what Mark suggested is correct. I recommend select2. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: +1, came in here to suggest either select2 or chosen (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: As mark pointed out Selection2 seem to be a good solution, using the dropdown combined with a search filter. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 was a great solution.
Thanks to Mark Baker and Doink for pointing out that direction in the commments.

Having several  values is not a problem itself, it is however not useable for the end user when it became hundreds of values.

Select2 offer a nice solution and filter out unwanted result in a handy way.
Easy to implement as well.

Answer (score 0):

150 values in a `select` field is ok no problem, I have seen more and working good.

You can use a code like this to make it nicer and more accessible:

```
<select name="names" size="5" id="names">
  <option>val1</option>
  <option>val2</option>
  <option>val3</option>
  <option>val4</option>
  ...
  <option>val150</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think that will be kind of bad experience for the user to have a mile long drop down.